# NSStringFromClass performance in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: objective-c, performance, uitableview

Somewhere in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {`:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TagCell";
TagCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier
                                                forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

vs

```
NSString *CellIdentifier = NSStringFromClass([TagCell class]);
TagCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier
                                                forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

I think the first example better for performance, but the second better for refactoring.

I always use the second way.

Big a difference in performance between these code samples?

Comment: The identifiers can be anything. There is no relationship between the cell identifier and the cell's class. You could quite literally use `@"Foo"` for the identifier just as well as `@"TagCell"`. The choice of identifier is based on two factors: 1) Human readability, 2) Using unique identifiers in a given table when there are different types of cells in the table.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy I know about it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no noticeable performance difference between the two, because rendering of cells is dominated by drawing, not obtaining a class name. Your second code snippet survives refactoring better, so you should continue using it.

Comment: But you should probably take a few minutes to prove this to yourself using Instruments. It might reveal other things you hadn't thought of as well.

Answer (score 6):

```
    #define MacroStringFromClass(class) (@""#class)
    #define loopcout 1000000

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        [self loopForMacro];
        [self loopForString];
        [self loopForNSStringFromClass];
        [self loopForMacro];
        [self loopForString];
        [self loopForNSStringFromClass];
        [self loopForMacro];
        [self loopForString];
        [self loopForNSStringFromClass];

    }
    - (void)loopForMacro{
        NSDate *startDate = [NSDate date];
        NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString string];
        for (int i = 0; i < loopcout; i++) {
            [str appendString:MacroStringFromClass(ViewController)];
        }
        NSTimeInterval cost = [[NSDate date]timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];
        NSLog(@"loopForMacro cost:%f",cost);
    }

    - (void)loopForString{
        NSDate *startDate = [NSDate date];
        NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString string];
        for (int i = 0; i < loopcout; i++) {
            [str appendString:@"ViewController"];
        }
        NSTimeInterval cost = [[NSDate date]timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];
        NSLog(@"loopForString cost:%f",cost);
    }

    - (void)loopForNSStringFromClass{
        NSDate *startDate = [NSDate date];
        NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString string];
        for (int i = 0; i < loopcout; i++) {
            [str appendString:NSStringFromClass([ViewController class])];
        }
        NSTimeInterval cost = [[NSDate date]timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];
        NSLog(@"loopForNSStringFromClass cost:%f",cost);
    }
```

result:

```
2016-08-05 15:42:55.804 NSStringFromClassTest[40193:22217987] loopForMacro cost:0.092388
2016-08-05 15:42:55.919 NSStringFromClassTest[40193:22217987] loopForString cost:0.112828
2016-08-05 15:42:56.283 NSStringFromClassTest[40193:22217987] loopForNSStringFromClass cost:0.362415
2016-08-05 15:42:56.362 NSStringFromClassTest[40193:22217987] loopForMacro cost:0.076543
2016-08-05 15:42:56.440 NSStringFromClassTest[40193:22217987] loopForString cost:0.076628
2016-08-05 15:42:56.801 NSStringFromClassTest[40193:22217987] loopForNSStringFromClass cost:0.359302
2016-08-05 15:42:56.877 NSStringFromClassTest[40193:22217987] loopForMacro cost:0.074724
2016-08-05 15:42:56.953 NSStringFromClassTest[40193:22217987] loopForString cost:0.074211
2016-08-05 15:42:57.312 NSStringFromClassTest[40193:22217987] loopForNSStringFromClass cost:0.356701
```

Comment: Pretty sure that `MacroStringFromClass` doesn't give you the correct result, since that is evaluated during preprocessing, so the value will always be `ViewController`.